# How to get a div text from html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Hi I am trying to get the div data from another html page. For these I am get the html data through `$.ajax({});` it's returned bunch of html content from this I am trying to get div text but it's returning empty.

My Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
      url:'/Myrewards.asp',
      type:'GET',
      success: function(data) { 
        var result = $(data).filter("#content_area").html();
        var result_1 = $(data).filter("#rewards_point_display").text();
        console.log(result);
      }
   });
});
```

`result` is returned below html code.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div id="div_articleid_141">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/a/c/myrewards.css">    <div id="rewards_content">    <h3>MyRewards - Reap the rewards with every purchase</h3>    It pays to go with MyRewards. Every time you make a purchase with [your company or website's name], you'll receive points [if product based, then] for the product(s) you purchase [if total amount of purchase, then] based on your total purchase amount. It's a great way to save on your next purchase whether it's for you or someone special.    <h4>Here's how it works:</h4>    <ol>   <li>Once you've placed your order and it has shipped, your MyRewards Point will be redeemable in [X] days.</li>   <li>To view your MyRewards, simply go to <a href="/MyRewards.asp">MyRewards</a>.</li>   
<li>Enter the total amount (in points) you'd like to redeem below (X points = $X).</li>   <li>You're now ready to save on your next purchase. Upon placing your order, your available MyRewards will automatically be deducted from the total purchase amount.</li>  
</ol>    <div id="rewards_point_display">  Available Points: 100<br>  Pending Points: 0  </div>    <input id="points_to_redeem" name="points_to_redeem" value="100" type="text"> 
<input id="redeem_now_button" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/253/images/Buttons/btn_redeem.gif" value="Redeem" name="go" alt="Redeem" type="image">    
<div id="rewards_terms">Want to learn more about MyRewards? For more MyRewards information, see the <a href="articles.asp?ID=140">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</div>
</div></div>

</form>
```

from above text I am trying to get `rewards_point_display` div text, but it's not working.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you should use `jQuery.parseHTML()`

Parses a string into an array of DOM nodes.

```
var bad = $.parseHTML(result);
```

**OR**

Use `.filter()`

```
console.log($(result).filter('#rewards_point_display').html());
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

```js
var result = "<div>First Div</div><div id='rewards_point_display'>Text of rewards_point_display</div>";

//Use filter
console.log($(result).filter('#rewards_point_display').html());


//use parseHTML
var data = $.parseHTML(result);
$(data).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try jQuery `load()` like this:

```
var url = '/Myrewards.asp';
$('.whereyouwanttoinsert').load(url + ' #rewards_point_display');
```

Comment: ye, I didn't bother to read the code that much, just went with the name :)